# Shall i upgrade Database server from 2005 to 2012 without upgrading SSRS or web Application

Tags: sql-server-2005, upgrade

Shall i upgrade Database server from 2005 to 2012 without upgrading SSRS or web Application relying upon the database?
Will the SSRS reports and Web application continue to work?
Would be appreciated if you could respond quickly

Comment: Are you asking if this is a good idea, or if it is a supported configuraiton or if it will work irrespective of its support status?  Have you read the documentation that comes with the product, concerning compatibility and upgrades?  Is there a problem in there or an statement you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Will suggest you to go through this whitepaper [SQL Server 2012 Upgrade Technical Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/3/9533501A-6F3E-4D03-A6A3-359AF6A79877/SQL_Server_2012_Upgrade_Technical_Reference_Guide_White_Paper.pdf), to get a proper understanding on what all is needed for the activity.

There are many points which would be need to be think upon, i.e.

> Just upgrading by keeping the compatibility level at a older version is not real upgrade. Evaluate at using some of the new features to increase productivity, performance, maintainability and scalability.

As the upgrade talks happens, get started with tracking if any deprecated features are being used. There are multiple ways to do this – I highly recommend using the “ [SQL Server: Deprecated Featurese](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510662.aspx)” Perfmon counter to track it like a background task. As your application runs, this gives you a rough idea of how many deprecated features you might be using inside your application that might have an impact to your upgrade process. There is also a Trace Event for capturing Deprecated features with SQL Server Profiler which you can use but that will be to nail down which code is causing that perfmon spike.

Also before upgrading you should check [Upgrade Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256.aspx) as a first step. This surely guides you of potential problems upfront and is one of the essential step too for any SQL Server upgrade process.

Also, you need to understand on the OS version. If you're current OS running sql server 2005 is good enough to run SQL server 2012.

Similarly, when you check for apps and SSRS, you need to test their functionality if they are designed to run and function as per the latest SQL server 2012 features.

So, before coming to conclusion you need to have a thorough testing done on test/dev/staging servers to test the above apps\reports.

Get everything documented and then layout a plan to decided a YES or NO.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not good to uprgade only SQL Server. 2005 is out of support so I think you need to upgrade SSRS also.

If you update only SQL server you must check you apps, bacuse there are some issues with SQLs between versions. For example we use SQLs generated in concatenated strings and we have some issues when upgrading from 2000 to 2008.

In any case you must make test how apps work with the new version the new version.

So my answer is NO.